# "Brave as a "King"" is our beginning, this puzzle is about a beginning

Tags: word, knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, visual

Me (my friends call me "King") and my friends, who are all puzzle loving university students, have just recently started to give each other puzzles to solve once a day. This day was my turn (first time) to solve a puzzle created by them.

Written on a paper was an image of some sort and only a short text, where it said the following:

*Once the time is right, narrow it down, in a way that makes perfect sense, to a **four-digit number**  and give us the **nine-letter** answer to this puzzle. You probably gonna like this one King... You share something in common with the answer ;)*

[image]

[image]

---

**What nine-letter answer should I give them?**

Comment: @ACB The knowledge tag only applies to the last step. But it's nothing complicated. For some it might require for them to use Google/wiki but for most I believe not.

Comment: Well, I think a letter is misplaced in the third graph. Also I have an idea about ----- but not sure how the clock applies.

Comment: @ACB I can't find any mistake there... Yes, keep thinking, now you gotta make sense of how to apply the first part to the second part.

Comment: I know how to interpret the grids, but I can't find meaningful data using those grid results on the clock

Comment: @ArturoVialArqueros Ok. First, make sure you realize **how to** interpret the grid results on the clock. If you're sure of **how to**, then it should leave you with some new info. It might not look right, but try to make it fit the instructions in the text.

Comment: I'm not satisfied with the title, and some of the text, I tried to be as cryptic as I could but it doesn't make sense as it is right now, so I'll change it a bit, but not too much. Use that as a hint.

Comment: As you say there's no mistake, I'm confused. Rot13(V pna rkgenpg gjb qvtvg ahzoref sebz gur svefg gjb barf, ohg guveq bar qbrf abg tvir n cebcre ahzore. Vs V pna ercynpr n yrggre V pna trg nabgure ahzore.)

Comment: I'll make it clear, if others might be stuck on that one too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the nine-letter answer to this puzzle is:

> **Fibonacci**

I started by extracting letters from each grid, which is achieved by

> looking at the intersections of two lines of the same color.

This gives us:

> First grid: tisxy -> **sixty**
>
>  Second grid: teniny -> **ninety**
>
>  Third grid: rtithy -> **t*h*irty**

If we then

> apply a clockwise rotation of the corresponding number to each of the hands pictured by the grids, we get from the original time of 10:02:58 to a time of 1:12:03.

Then we can convert that time to a 4 digit number by simply:

> ignoring the zeroes, giving us a number of 1123.

Which you might notice is

> the *beginning* of the **fibonacci sequence:** 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8 ...

Thus, the nine letter solution of the puzzle must be:

> **fibonacci**

Comment: rot13(V qba'g xabj nobhg gur obggbz unys ohg sbe gur zvffvat 'u', V oryvrir jr gerng gur qbhoyr pbyberq onef nf zngpuvat *rvgure* pbybe (bayl rkgen yrggre nqqrq vf gur U))

Comment: You got the right method! And almost the correct number. I see how you got there, but my intention was to focus on each rot13(unaq vaqvivqhnyyl, urapr gur zvahgr unaq vf cbvagrq rknpgyl ng 02 jura vg fubhyq or cbvagvat irel pybfr gb 03.. fb gur pybpx vf 
abg ernyvfgvpnyyl nyvtarq, va gur svefg cynpr.) So just make that small change, and then think of a new answer.  And btw rot13("xvat" vf whfg svthengviryl, abg ernyyl n xvat) so try to make sense of the title also.

Comment: Well done! This is the intended answer. Regarding the title rot13(V'z njner gung vg'f hapyrne naq abg gur orfg, ohg V qvqa'g jnag gb fnl "oenir nf n yvba", orpnhfr n dhvpx Tbbtyr frnepu pbhyq tvir lbh n anzr. Fb V vavgvnyyl jnagrq gb anzr gur znva crefba "Yvba" va guvf chmmyr, ohg gubhtug vg jbhyq or n tvirnjnl pbzovarq jvgu gur gvgyr. Ur naq Svobanppv funer bar guvat va pbzzba. "Oenir nf n yvba" vf gurve ortvaavat naq jung gurl funer...)